# How to connect one module to another Intellij

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have this two modules inside a project in Intellij, both use Gradle as a build system, the client module and the server module
[project dir structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bqy4.png) I want the server module to access some client classes, (I will change that later). The IDE auto-complete finds the classes I want, but the build system can't seem to build correctly. I already have added the client module as a dependency inside the Project Structure [intellij contfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvYwW.png). Actually I will move these classes to a core module, but for now they're inside the client module as I was testing things with the client.

Tried to build my server module with some client classes.

Answer (score 0):

It's better you deploy the client module first and add it as a dependency in gradle in the server module (Don't add the dependency via the IDE). I think Intellij syncs dependencies from gradle. It happens like that for maven and I think it works in the same way for gradle.

Helpful links:
[Declaring Dependencies between Subprojects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html)

Comment: How? I have no idea of any of what you just said :)

Comment: Could you please add some explanation on how to do that? I tried adding a settings.gradle to the project folder with include: 'core', 'client', 'server' it didnt work, tried adding implementation to build.gradle, tried somethin with client and server own settings.gradle and still it just doesnt work. Ive been trying all day and couldnt

Comment: I have added a link in my answer. Note that there will be 3 Gradle files. One for the root project, one of the server submodule and another for client submodule. In the link they add submodule named `shared` as dependency to the `api` module. You have to add dependency like `implementation project(':client')` in the build.gradle file of the `server` module.

Answer (score 0):

Add another shared module right away.There is no reason to wait with it and look for strange workaround that will be removed anyway (therefore are waste of time).

Comment: I tried to that already, couldn't do it anyway.

Comment: Could you please add some explanation on how to do that? I tried adding a settings.gradle to the project folder with include: 'core', 'client', 'server' it didnt work, tried adding implementation to build.gradle, tried somethin with client and server own settings.gradle and still it just doesnt work. Ive been trying all day and couldnt

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html